# Re-initialize map or reload component when language is changed

Tags: angular

I am using Google Maps Javascript API in my Angular 7 project in order to have a map. When the user changes the language from the menu, I change the API language and I store the change in localstorage.
The menu and the map are on different components and there is no parent-child relationship between them. How can I re-initialize or reload the map (or the component) when the language is changed?

Comment: also try changeDetectorRef.detechChanges(), otherwise check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a state management system to store the values in memory, but load it from local storage, and save it to local storage, you can dispatch an action from the component that selects the language, and select the value from the map component, for an example check out this:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uhapsa